# Mahalanobis distance inverting the covariance matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

I am writing a function to take the Mahalanobis distance between two vectors. I understand that this is achieved using the equation a'*C^-1*b, where a and b are vectors and C is the covariance matrix. My question is, is there an efficient way to find the inverse of the matrix without using Gauss-Jordan elimination, or is there no way around this? I'm looking for a way to do this myself, not with any predefined functions.

I know that C is a Hermitian, positive definite matrix, so is there any way that I can algorithmically take advantage of this fact? Or is there some clever way compute the Mahalanobis distance without calculating the inverse of the covariance at all? Any help would be appreciated.

***Edit: The Mahalanobis distance equation above is incorrect. It should be
x'*C^-1*x where x = (b-a), and b and a are the two vectors whose distance we are trying to find (thanks LRPurser). The solution posited in the selected answer is therefore as follows:

d=x'*b, where b = C^-1*x
C*b = x, so solve for b using LU factorization or LDL' factorization.

Comment: Gauss-Jordan elimination *is* the efficient way to invert a matrix (or at least solve a linear system). One of them, at least.

Comment: You can use [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) to solve linear equations with positive definite system matrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can (and should!) use [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) instead of explicitly inverting the matrix:  solving `C x = b` using a decomposition has better numeric properties than computing `C^-1` and multiplying the vector `b`.

Since your matrix is symmetric, an LU decomposition is effectively equivalent to an [LDL* decomposition](https://vismor.com/documents/network_analysis/matrix_algorithms/S7.SS2.php), which is what you should actually use in your case.  Since your matrix is also positive-definite, you should be able to perform this decomposition without pivoting.

---

Edit:  note that, for this application, you don't need to solve the full `C x = b` problem.

Instead, given `C = L D L*` and difference vector `v = a-b`, solve `L* y = v` for `y` (which is half as much work as the full LU solver).

Then, `y^t D^-1 y =  v^t C^-1 v` can be computed in linear time.

Comment: So solve the system C*x=b, and then multiply a'*b to get the norm, that's perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know about QR factorization? My understanding is that it's more mathematically stable than LU factorization, and it's what MATLAB uses when it solves linear systems. Do you know how this would compare to LDL* factorization in this situation?

Comment: I don't know offhand what QR might gain you, sorry.  If you think you might have stability problems with un-pivoted LDL*, then try QR as well and see if it helps...

Comment: No problem. I generally use QR factorization over LU factorization, but in this case I suspect that LDL* factorization might actually be better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

First Mahalanobis Distance (MD) is the normed distance with respect to uncertainty in the measurement of two vectors. When `C=Indentity matrix`, MD reduces to the Euclidean distance and thus the product reduces to the vector norm. Also MD is always positive definite or greater than zero for all non-zero vectors. By your formulation with the appropriate choice of the vectors `a` and `b`, `a*C^-1*b` can be less than zero. Hopefully the difference of vectors you are looking for is `x=(a-b)` which makes the calculation `x^t*C^-1*x` where `x^t` is the transpose of the vector `x`. Also note that `MD=sqrt(x^t*C^-1*x)`
Since your matrix is symmetric and positive definite then you can utilize the Cholesky decomposition `(MatLab-chol)` which uses half of the operations as LU and is numerically more stable. `chol(C)=L` where `C=L*L^t` where `L` is a lower triangular matrix and `L^t` is the transpose of `L` which make it upper triangular. Your algorithm should go something like this

(Matlab)

```
  x=a-b;
  L=chol(C); 
  z=L\x; 
  MD=z'*z; 
  MD=sqrt(MD);
```

Comment: According to http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users, chol(a) returns an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Is `MD=z'*z; MD=sqrt(MD);` just the norm of z?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Mahalanobis Distance Matrix

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

# Example
Data = np.array([[1,2],[3,2],[4,3]])
Cov = np.cov(np.transpose([[1,2],[3,2],[4,3]]))
invCov = np.linalg.inv(Cov)

Y = pdist(Data, 'mahalanobis', invCov)
MD = squareform(Y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: with *pdist*  you calculated **pairwise distance** between observations in n-dimensional space `pdist(x, 'mahalanobis', VI= invCov)` and *mahalanobis distance* is  a measure between a sample point and a distribution, where *VI : ndarray The inverse of the covariance matrix for Mahalanobis. Default: inv(cov(X.T)).T*

Comment: `squareform` just "converts between condensed distance matrices and *square distance matrices*", or can convert to *Compressed Sparse Row matrix* with  `md = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(dist_matrix_your_Y)`

Answer (score 0):

for centered data like [here](https://www.statology.org/mahalanobis-distance-python/) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23685080/15893581)
edit2)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mahalanobis(x=None, data=None, cov=None):
    # demean by columns/features to center data
    x_mu = x - np.mean(data)
    if not cov:
        cov = np.cov(data.values.T)
    inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    left = np.dot(x_mu, inv_covmat)
    mahal = np.dot(left, x_mu.T)
    return mahal.diagonal()

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,2],[4,3]])
df= df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['score',  'grade'])
print(df)

#create new column in dataframe that contains Mahalanobis distance for each row
df['mahalanobis'] = mahalanobis(x=df, data=df[['score',  'grade']])
print(df)
```

p.s.
[Mahalanobis Distance](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/statistics/mahalanobis-distance/)

[Kernel Mahalanobis Distances](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/ians/haasdonk/publications/HP08b.pdf)

[Proposed Mahalanobis distance–based kernel supervised machine learning](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1550147720968467)

[Learning the Kernel in
Mahalanobis One-Class Support Vector Machines](https://cse.hkust.edu.hk/%7Ejamesk/papers/ijcnn06a.pdf)