# How to calculate a Cholesky decomposition of a non square matrix in order to calculate the Mahalanobis Distance with `numpy`?

Tags: python, numpy

How to calculate a Cholesky decomposition of a non square matrix in order to calculate the Mahalanobis Distance with `numpy`?

```
def get_fitting_function(G):
    print(G.shape) #(14L, 11L) --> 14 samples of dimension 11
    g_mu = G.mean(axis=0) 
    #Cholesky decomposition uses half of the operations as LU
    #and is numerically more stable.
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(G)

    def fitting_function(g):
        x = g - g_mu
        z = np.linalg.solve(L, x)
        #Mahalanobis Distance 
        MD = z.T*z
        return math.sqrt(MD)
    return fitting_function  


C:\Users\Matthias\CV\src\fitting_function.py in get_fitting_function(G)
     22     #Cholesky decomposition uses half of the operations as LU
     23     #and is numerically more stable.
---> 24     L = np.linalg.cholesky(G)
     25 
     26     def fitting_function(g):

C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc in cholesky(a)
    598     a, wrap = _makearray(a)
    599     _assertRankAtLeast2(a)
--> 600     _assertNdSquareness(a)
    601     t, result_t = _commonType(a)
    602     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'

C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc in _assertNdSquareness(*arrays)
    210     for a in arrays:
    211         if max(a.shape[-2:]) != min(a.shape[-2:]):
--> 212             raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
    213 
    214 def _assertFinite(*arrays):

LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square 


    LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Based on Matlab implementation of: [Mahalanobis distance inverting the covariance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785201/mahalanobis-distance-inverting-the-covariance-matrix/11799356#11799356)

Edit: `chol(a)` **=** `linalg.cholesky(a).T`
cholesky factorization of a matrix (`chol(a)` in matlab returns an upper triangular matrix, but `linalg.cholesky(a)` returns a lower triangular matrix) (source: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users))

Edit2:

```
G -= G.mean(axis=0)[None, :]
C = (np.dot(G, G.T) / float(G.shape[0]))
#Cholesky decomposition uses half of the operations as LU
#and is numerically more stable.
L = np.linalg.cholesky(C).T
```

so if D=x^t.S^-1.x=x^t.(L.L^t)^-1.x=x^t.L.L^t.x=z^t.z

Comment: Why don't you use [`scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html)?

Comment: 2.) I'm pretty sure all decompositions require square matrices (usually hermitian or unitary matrices are required, which are square).  Numpy is clearly complaining about the squareness of your matrix.  Shouldn't you be computing the distance between each pair of the 14 vectors in your array?  The covariance matrix of each pair is square.

Comment: Wikipedia: Cholesky decomposition
Applicable to: square, symmetric, positive definite matrix A; your indeed right

Comment: @larsmans I don't want to directly invoke a command for calculating the inverse which is needed as an input argument.

Comment: re: your second edit, there's no need for Python loops - you can centre all of the rows at once using broadcasting: `G -= G.mean(0)[None, :]`

Comment: why use `T`  in your `Edit` - seems no need: check reconstructed matrix with `print(np.allclose( np.dot(L,L.T.conj()), C))` after `L = np.linalg.cholesky(C)` to get `True` --  for any square positive definite matrix e.g. `G= np.array([[1.,3.,5.], [3.,13.,23.], [5.,23.,42.]])`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. Cholesky decomposition requires not only a square matrix, but a Hermitian matrix one, and a positive definite matrix for uniqueness. It is basically an LU decomposition, with the proviso that L = U'. In fact, the algorithm is frequently used as a way to numerically check that a given matrix is positive definite. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

That said, a covariance matrix is symmetric postive semidefinite by definition, so you should be able to do cholesky on it.

Edit: As you calculate it, your matrix `C=np.dot(G, G.T)` should be symmetric, but maybe something is wrong. You could try forcibly symmetrizing it `C = ( C + C.T) /2.0`, and try  `chol(C)` again.

Comment: it can occur to be not  *positive definite*! ( for cholesky decomposition)... (though the idea to avoid matrix inverse is a good idea for the stability of calculations)

Comment: cholesky  math for mahalanobis calculations [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147210/efficient-fast-mahalanobis-distance-computation)

Comment: [Max-Mahalanobis Linear Discriminant Analysis Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09308.pdf)